# Can a vow of celibacy for 2 months be taken back?

Tags: vedas

I took a vow that I would not masturbate for 2 months. Only 6 days into this, I cannot deal with this any longer.Please note that I have Obsessive compulsive disorder so it is possible that I took my vow because of that. I am not sure of it myself

Comment: Why would you want to become celibate? Almost all hindu gods are not celibate.

Comment: @Wikash_ The question is not about deities. This doesn't look a constructive comment.

Comment: This isn't at all personal advice. If it were the OP would take decision on his own or from other online sources. He's more interested about rules of vow.

Comment: Don't worry about it. Try reading some books which will help you achieve your goal whatever you truly desire. Only follow it if it truly makes sense to you. Don't follow blindly which just makes you more frustrated, annoyed, and lost but nothing else. Try to seek what you really want. Know yourself first.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Any vow or promise that affects you or someone else negatively, should be broken unless you want to prove to yourself that you have strength to keep it.

If you don't, even when you're *suffering*, sooner or later you'll realize you did a bad thing. It wasn't necessary. There's no rule that you must keep doing something if you've taken a vow. Rules should be for solving problems or for some benefits rather than creating problems. I don't see anything wrong in it.

After all, what's a vow? It's something you believe in and you feel you must not break the promise related to it. But no one knows if it was right thing or wrong. Only experience will tell you that. If you feel you've gained enough experience in 6 days, break the promise!